# JavaScript - Date.now() returning incorrect date

Tags: javascript, date

I want to get the amount of days between a set date and today.

I can't figure out why I keep getting wrong results when I get today's date dynamically instead of hard-coding it.

HTML

```
<span id="today1">xxx</span> days - wrong
<br>
<span id="today2">xxx</span> days - wrong
<br>
<span id="hardcoded">xxx</span> days - correct
```

JS

```
var startDate = new Date(2016,04,01).getTime();
var todayDate1 = new Date().getTime();
var todayDate2 = Date.now();
var hardcodedDate = new Date(2018,04,08).getTime();

$("#today1").html(Math.floor((todayDate1 - startDate)/8.64e7));
$("#today2").html(Math.floor((todayDate2 - startDate)/8.64e7));
$("#hardcoded").html(Math.floor((hardcodedDate - startDate)/8.64e7));
```

Result

```
707 days - wrong
707 days - wrong
737 days - correct
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uudaa1c1/9/)

What am I missing?

Comment: What date do you think `new Date(2016,04,01)` gives you? Hint: It's about a month from now, not today. Edit: Not sure why I'm being coy with it: Month numbers start at 0 = January.

Comment: (Side note: Strongly recommend not using leading `0`s on numbers, although in modern JavaScript engines it shouldn't trigger old-style octal parsing.)

Comment: Month `4` is May.

Comment: Thanks to all. Sorted now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Today is April 8th, 2018. `new Date(2018, 4, 8)` is **May** 8th, 2018. Quoting the [MDN documentation on the `Date` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

> The argument month is `0-based`. This means that `January = 0` and `December = 11`.

Use `3` as the month parameter to refer to April.

Comment: Thank you, setting the startDate to Date(2016,03,01) gave me the result I needed.